# tableView return function not getting the data from API Call instead its making the tableView empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made API file with the request data in Json, also made a different structure of the type data that will come but I am having problems retrieving the data, its showing empty tableView instead of showing at least the cells I made.

This is the return code for tableView:

```
extension MonitorimiViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return vehicles.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monitorimiCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell1
    cell.configure()
    return cell   
}
```

This is the structure file with the data that must be filled in the Cell labels:

```
struct Vehicles: Codable {

var  Plate: String?
var  Speed: Int
var  LastCommunicationDate: Int
var  Passengers: Int
var  Driver: String

}
```

And this is the API request file:

```
class APICaller {

static let shared = APICaller()
private let baseURL = "http://000.000.000.000:3030/api/"

private init() {}

func getVehicles(for id: String, IMEI: Int, completed: @escaping (Result<[Vehicles],OnTraErrors>) -> Void ){
    let endpoint = baseURL + "GetVehicle/?UserIdentificationValue=JJGI243GJI3G&IMEI=623624346236"
    
    let headers = [
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "authorizetoken": "NjQzOPA2N0NDNDFAH4CNDk3R23F2FQUY0NjV3FFE=",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                ]
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        completed(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 120)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let vehicles = try decoder.decode([Vehicles].self, from: data)
            completed(.success(vehicles))
        } catch {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

So when I change the return vehicles.count to return 10 it just shows my cells like this : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVp5Z.png

but right now its showing me this instead of filling those labels [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG4bb.png

Comment: reload your table view after getting the results

Comment: I am not sure how are you configuring your cells, but i can see you're not passing details for the cell by just calling `cell.configure()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you're reloading your `UITableView` you can simply observe the dataSource variable

```
    var vehicles: [Vehicles] = [] { // i suggest renaming Vehicles struct to vehicle
        didSet {
                tableView.reloadDate()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response mate, where should I put this code also its showing error on didSet

Comment: you're view controller show me the variable vehicles, or just replace it with this

Comment: @L1S check the updated one.

Comment: I did make a var vehicles = [Vehicles]() on the top so it can call it, then I added this to the functionalists tableView let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monitorimiCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell1
        tableView.reloadData()
        return cell

Comment: replca it with what i added and retry

Comment: remove reload from ur cell for row function

Comment: hey I posted an answer if you could tell me which place I should edit it and put it since I couldn't fix it till now tons of errors